# Django Queryset check value if exists

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two values to check if it's existed in my PostgreSQL. I also have columns named `ref_name, ref_surname`
for example:

```
//this is the data//
name: John
Surname: Lee

//this is some queryset from django//
Employee.objects.filter(ref_name=name & ref_surname=Surname).exists()
```

I want to check if the data is already existed in my database. I have read the Queryset documentation and I can't find an answer. I'm open to any suggestion.

Comment: what's happening after running above code

Comment: syntax invalid. My queryset approach is wrong

Comment: can you show me that error?

Comment: You don't have to put `&`(invalid syntax) inside `filter()` just seprate them by comma it will give same resut

Comment: print(TEmployee.objects.filter(ref_name=name & ref_surname=Surname).existss())
                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Try this `Employee.objects.filter(ref_name=name, ref_surname=Surname).exists()`

Comment: @GnaniKim `&` is used `Q` objects so `Employee.objects.filter(Q(ref_name=name) & Q(ref_surname=Surname)).exists()` it is the right query with `&`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Employee.objects.filter(ref_name=name, ref_surname=Surname).exists()
```

You don't have to put `&` which is an invalid syntax inside the `filter()` just separate them by a comma `,` it will give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Employee.objects.filter(ref_name=name & ref_surname=Surname).exists()
```

to this:

```
Employee.objects.filter(ref_name=name, ref_surname=Surname).exists()
```

You can separate using comma, not &.

Answer (score 0):

if Employee.objects.filter(ref_name=name and ref_surname=Surname).exists()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).